# Programmatic Object Creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following hard coded object:

```
data.Add(New Object() {"Date", "Minutes"})
```

How do I create an object like this from a for each?  For instance:

```
For each item in group

    ' do something

Next
```

*(When "group" contains "Date" and "Minutes.")*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do this:

```
data = group.Select(Function(item) new YourObject() With {.Date = item.Date, .Minutes = item.Minutes }).ToList()
```

If you really want to do it in a `For Each` loop, you can use:

```
For Each item In group
    data.Add(new YourObject() With {.Date = item.Date, .Minutes = item.Minutes })
Next
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking for a way to do it with a `for each` though, if possible.

Comment: @user1477388 Added that for you, too

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is what I was looking for.